# Setting karma jasmine DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL globally

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, angular-test

In my Angular app, I use Karma and Jasmine to run my unit tests.

I'd like to change the default timeout interval for async tests, from the 5 seconds default to, let's say, 10 seconds.

I see that you can use `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000` to accomplish it.

However, I'd like to change it globally, via some configuration file. For example in `karma.conf.js` but I don't see the `defaultTimeoutInterval` option available.

Answer (score 18):

I've found the answer in the [karma-jasmine](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine#configuration) GitHub repo.

It looks like the right key is `timeoutInterval` inside `karma.conf.js`:

```js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        random: true,
        seed: '4321',
        oneFailurePerSpec: true,
        failFast: true,
        timeoutInterval: 10000 // <- this is what I was looking for
      }
    }
  })
}
```